# In bootstrap how do I make my card div responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

The section I am doing is just 6 cards, 3 cards in a row of 2. When the screen goes to small (mobile phone size) I want each card just to be on their own row. Each card showing one by one as the user scrolls.

It functions this way when I resize the screen however, when I go to google tools, it does not show my desired outcome.

```css
.row {
  padding: 4rem;
  background-color: #F8F8FF;
  border: 4px black;
  colour: red;
}

.card {
  background-color: #ddf;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 20px;
  transition: 0.40s;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container ">
  <h1 class="display-4">My Projects/Work</h1>
  
  <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card" id="proj1">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="card-img-top" alt="project_1" />

        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Blog Project</h5>
          
          <p class="card-text">
            A simple blog website which I made from scratch using html , css and javascript for the frontend.The backend was done with Django and SQL.
          </p>
          
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Click to see</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card" id="proj2">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="card-img-top" alt="project_2" />

        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Social media clone </h5>
          
          <p class="card-text">
            A social media clone with all the main features of a social media site such as Facebook.In order to achieve this I used Django and React.
          </p>
          
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Click to see</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card" id="proj3">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="card-img-top" alt="project_3" />

        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">E-commence site</h5>
          
          <p class="card-text">
            This is a website I build for a small tech company in my local area that specialized in databases .

          </p>
          
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Click to see</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Protip: It's a very bad idea to put custom styles on primary library layout elements. You end up working against the intent of the library and imparting styles where they aren't wanted. Your row padding should be margin on the column content (or set with Bootstrap's layout [customization options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid)).

Comment: Colors and borders should be done with custom classes (or the ones Bootstrap provides for [border](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/borders/#color) and [background](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/background/#background-color)).

Comment: I wanted to ask the same question as isherwood, what do you mean by "Google tools"? Are you talking about screen sizes in developer tools? If it works when you resize it, that should be it already.

Comment: When you speak about your "desired outcome", is it about the 3 rows per col and 1 per col in mobile, or something else ?

Comment: @isherwood thanks for the Pro tip . When I said google tools I meant. When I click inspect on my website and go to the development tools on google chrome. Then click the option to view my site to see what it would look like on a mobile device.

Comment: @Cédric I think the issue I was having was by me putting 6 cards on 2 different rows. When I just placed 6 cards in 1 row I found that I had more control over how I wanted my elements to behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Answers should have some explanation. Please see [answer].

Comment: This made me realize when I just placed 6 cards in 1 row I found that I had more control over how I wanted my elements to behave. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put classes on "row" or "column" https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#align-items

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="bg-light pt-5 pb-5 shadow-sm">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row pt-5">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h3 class="text-uppercase border-bottom mb-4">Bootstrap Responsive</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="card-img-top" alt="Card Image">
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h5 class="card-title">Blog Project</h5>
            <p class="card-text mb-4">A simple blog website which I made from scratch using html , css and javascript for the frontend.The backend was done with Django and SQL.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto align-self-start">Click to see</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="card-img-top" alt="Card Image">
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h5 class="card-title">Blog Project</h5>
            <p class="card-text mb-4">A simple blog website which I made from scratch using html , css and javascript for the frontend.The backend was done with Django and SQL.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto align-self-start">Click to see</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="card-img-top" alt="Card Image">
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h5 class="card-title">Blog Project</h5>
            <p class="card-text mb-4">A simple blog website which I made from scratch using html , css and javascript for the frontend.The backend was done with Django and SQL.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto align-self-start">Click to see</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]